# Clojure calling Java, different projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, clojure, clojure-java-interop

Im using eclipse 4.6.0 and ccw 0.35.0. This is my java-code in project java1

```
package mypkg;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(mul2(42));
    }
    public static long mul2(long x) {
        return x*2;
    }
}
```

it runs fine as a java-program and prints 84. This is the clojure-code:

```
(ns clojure2.core
  (:import [mypkg Main]))

(println (Main/mul2 17))
```

when run by the REPL the result is

```
CompilerException java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mypkg.Main, compiling:(clojure2/core.clj:1:1)
```

I have added project java1 to project clojure2 in `properties->java build path->projects` but it doesn't seem to work. I guess adding it there is for the java-compiler, but how do I add it to the REPL?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe in the run configuration you are using to launch the clojure program? clj has a class path argument, if I remember correctly...

Comment: I'm unable to find how to configure the startup of the REPL.

Comment: Eclipse menu -> Run -> Run configurations?

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean, so I made a new clojure-configuration, java1 was already in the classpath probably from adding it to the build-path as above, but it still doesn't work. Is the clojure-code wrong? I've done it differently so many times now I don't know whats right or wrong anymore.

Comment: The only way I can make it work so far is to copy the folder mypkg with the class-file in the bin-folder from project java1 to the src-folder in project clojure2.

Comment: By default I believe CCW use a generic leiningen-based run conf. You have to manually create a run config (which bypass lein) to access the "java build path" of the JDT.

Comment: Yes, I believe you're right, I'm reading up on maven to do that, convert both projects to maven and then adjust the configurations to mirror my intensions.